# Multiple directives - Accessing element from scope method

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create two directives: clonable and removable.
These will show a copy and a remove button and if clicked will be copied and/or removed from dom.

The problem I am facing, if copy it is getting wrong element!
If I copy the div, it actually copies the image!

```
app.directive('removable', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
            var removeBtn;
            $element.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
              console.warn("mouseenter-remove");    
                            console.warn($element)
                removeBtn = angular.element("<button ng-click='remove($event)'>Delete</button>");
                $element.append(removeBtn);
                $compile(removeBtn)($scope);

            });

            $element.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.warn("mouseleave-remove");    
                            console.warn($element)
                                removeBtn.hide();
            });


            $scope.remove = function ($event) {
                            console.warn("remove");    
                            console.warn($element)
                $element.hide();
                removeBtn.remove();
            }          
        }
    };
});


app.directive('clonable', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
            var copyBtn;
            var copyTimeout;

            $element.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
 console.warn('mouseenter- copy');     
                console.warn($element);
                e.preventDefault();

                copyBtn = angular.element("<button ng-click='copy($event)'>Copy</div>");
                $element.after(copyBtn);
                $compile(copyBtn)($scope);

            });

            $element.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
            console.warn('mouseleave- copy');     
                console.warn($element); 
                e.preventDefault();
                                copyBtn.fadeOut("slow");
            });          

            $scope.copy = function ($event) {
console.warn('copy');     
                console.warn($element);                
                $element.after($element.clone());
                copyBtn.remove();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/1553/). If copy "TEST TEST" it will actually copy the image

Comment: Can you update the jsfiddle link. I think it is the incorrect one. All it displays is: "Hello John Lindquist"

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBiggs, it's updated now